# Using pre-defined string for "Path" attribute in FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, winforms, filesystemwatcher

I'm making a simple winforms application in `C#`, with `VS2010`. My winforms design contains a `FileSystemWatcher`, which fires a pile of code when a file is created.

My problem is that the path for `FileSystemWatcher` needs to be defined prior to the program running, as it won't always be the same.

I have a string called startPath which I'd like to use, but it would appear that I can't just add this to the "path" field in the `FileSystemWatcher` properties in my design.

I was able to get it to work if I edited my `form1.designer.cs`, but as I swiftly learned this code is regenerated even if a different component of the form is edited!

As you might have guessed, I'm still very much *learning* `C#.net` (about a week in), and am by no means experienced! If I'm missing something stupid, please point it out!

Comment: 2 words: Application settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FileSystemWatcher has a path property that can be used to change the path after the FileSystemWatcher object is initialized. Otherwise, you'll have to re-setup your watcher if you use the constructor to set the path to watch.

[FileSystemWatcher.Path Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.path.aspx)

Storing the path itself can be easily done through the Application Settings as mentioned by @leppie

Reference for settings:
[Application Settings Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx)
[Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
[Saving User Settings in Winform Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/350010/Saving-User-Settings-in-Winform-Application)

Comment: Reading your link about FileSystemWatcher.Path is what really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I assigned my user defined string as the path at run time like so:

In my form1.cs:

```
protected override void  OnActivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnActivated(e);
            fileSystemWatcher1.Path = inputPath;
    }
```

I *think* this is an ok way of doing it (it seems to be working!), the string "inputPath" is defined earlier by getting the corresponding setting from my configuration file. It just didn't seem to want to play nice if I placed it settings.cs.

Answer (score -1):

Add the required path to the appSettings part of your app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="watcherPath" value="\\myPC\myShare\myFolder\" />  
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then you can access this value from with your code, and assign it to the FileWatcher path:

```
string myPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["watcherPath"];
FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(myPath);
```

Comment: Defining my path wasn't really the problem, it was finding a way of making sure that the user defined path actually got "assigned" to my FileSystemWatcher at run time. Your way doesn't take into account that my FileSystemWatcher is initialised in the autogenerated "form1.designer.cs" file. (unless I'm missing something!)